# \n "unexpected character after line continuation character"

Tags: python

I have a recurring problem when trying to use \n in python. I'm trying to get the code to write to a text file after extracting data from another text file howeve when i run the code it always shows a  "unexpected character after line continuation character" error after the \n.  This is the code i am currently using.

```
while True:
 while True:
    try:
        Prod_Code = input("enter an 8 digit number or type Done to get your final receipt: ")
        check = len(Prod_Code)
        int(Prod_Code) 

        if check == 8:
            print("This code is valid")



            with open('Data Base.txt', 'r') as searchfile:
                for line in searchfile:
                    if Prod_Code in line:
                        print(line)
                        receipt = open('Receipt.txt', 'w')
                        receipt.write(line, \n)
                        receipt.close()
                        break

        else:
            print("incorrect length, try again")

    except ValueError:
        if Prod_Code == "Done":
            print("Your receipt is being calculated")
            exit()

        else:
             print("you must enter an integer")
```

Comment: write `"\n"` instead and make it a +, so `line + "\n"`

Comment: it needs to be `'\n'`

Answer (score 2):

unlike `print`, `write` accepts only one argument (also you cannot write floats & ints without converting them to string - not the issue here).

And your `\n` char must be quoted of course. So write:

```
receipt.write(line + "\n")
```

Following your comment, it appears that your code doesn't work as expected, even after this fix because you're writing only one line (no append) *and* you break the loop as soon as you match 1 line: 2 reasons for writing only one line. I propose the following fix:

```
receipt = None

with open('Data Base.txt', 'r') as searchfile:
    for line in searchfile:
        if Prod_Code in line:
            print(line)
            if receipt == None:
                receipt = open('Receipt.txt', 'w')
            receipt.write(line+"\n")

if receipt != None:
   receipt.close()
```

the output file will only be created if there's a match. It stays open during the loop and the lines are thus appended. In the end, it closes the file if required.

Note that this kind of linear search is not optimal if you perform the operation many times. It would be better to store the contents of the file in a `list` and then iterate on the lines. But that's another story...

Comment: This has solved the problem however the program still writes to the same line  every time and doesn't start a new line. Any ideas on how to fix this?

Comment: @joewalley `receipt = open('Receipt.txt', 'w')` opens the file in write mode each time, so will overwrite the previous data and start all over again.

Comment: Ahhh right, thankyou. Everything works as it should now.

Comment: @joewalley are you sure? because there's a `break` which also prevents to write more than 1 line. Well, I have edited my post (but did not test it since I'm not sure now of what you expect)

Comment: The break is there to break the second while True loop so another number can be inputted, the numbers then correspond to a line in the Data Base text file. The program then writes that line to the Receipt texts file and breaks the loop taking it back to the top meaning the user can enter another number